# Winform extended control not showing up in the form designer

Tags: c#, events, combobox, overriding

I have extended a ComboBox to override the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event. The control works as intended. When the form that the control has been placed on is opened, the control displays. After running the application in debug mode and looking at the form (that was open when debugging started) the control is not visible. It is still there, just not visible. If the form is closed and opened again, the control is then visible.

Here is an example of my extended combo box:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public partial class ComboBoxSN : ComboBox
    {
        private bool _haltSelection = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Set whether to run the selectedindex event for the control
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Set this to true to keep the selected index from firing"), Category("CustomControl"), DefaultValue(false), Browsable(true)]
        public bool HaltSelection
        {
            get { return _haltSelection; }
            set { _haltSelection = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_haltSelection)
                base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The extended control is the the Toolbox.  I have removed and re-added the control to the Toolbox as suggested on another site with no luck.

Comment: Did you move the ComboBoxSN class to a new assembly? Is this happening every time you start debugging or happened just once?

Comment: It happens every time.  ComboBoxSN class is in the same assembly as the form